# Google Chat Bot doesn't receive non-mention message event in space

Tags: google-chat

I recently joined a team that uses Google Chat for notifications. The manager has asked me to research Google Chat Bot. In the future, we can add it to our space, and the chatbot can help us handle some issues.

After setting up the bot, I am in the debug mode, I add the Bot into a space, my backend successfully receives `ADDED_TO_SPACE` event, and so do a `REMOVED_FROM_SPACE` event when I remove the bot from space.

If someone send non-mention(to the bot) message to the space, the bot doesn't make any reply to the message. Also I even found that, backend didn't receive any incoming request. But if someone send mention the bot message, like `@BotName hi`, my backend and the bot do receive the message.

I think I might have missed some configurations that caused the Google Chat service to not send incoming requests to backend.

This is my test code

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot']

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('service_account.json', scopes=SCOPES)
chat = build('chat', 'v1', credentials=creds)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_bot_event():
    event_data = request.get_json()
    evt = event_data.get('type', None)
    space = event_data.get('space', None)
    
    if evt == 'MESSAGE':
        # handle MESSAGE event and make reply
    elif evt == 'ADDED_TO_SPACE' and space.get('type', None) == 'ROOM':
        # handle ADDED_TO_SPACE event
```

I run the dev server on localhost, and use ngrok to map the port, fill the ngrok URL into Google Chat like the following picture

[image: GoogleChatSetting]

I want the bot to receive all message event in the space. Is it possible? What should I do more?

I have read so many documents, but I think most of them apply to `Hangouts`, not apply for `Google Chat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Google chat doesn't support that feature.

You can check the supported event here:

https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/message-formats/events

So only mention message events that are sent to your app URL. Here is the flow
[image]

If you want to read all message, you can call message list endpoint periodically. That endpoint will show all messages from users, including non-mentioned message.

https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/list

Comment: Thank for your reply. I put much efforts recent days to findout if there is any method that could let the bot `receive non-mention message in space`, but seems it couldn't as you said. However, when I found [Google Chat apps - Preview links](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WVyG2L9gNc&ab_channel=GoogleWorkspaceDevelopers), I realized that my idea was overturned. So maybe it is possible to do that, but still not sure...

Comment: @TonyChou It's impossible for now. Preview Links only detect verified link only, so if there is no link in the message nor is there a link, but the link is not verified, we will not get the event.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Dyas Yaskur I'm a little confused with that. If I have already configured the Preview Link followed by [this post](https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/preview-links), for example: `https://tonychou.atlassian.net/jira/software/`, I think it is verified? (I'm not sure what you mean 'verified', because the post doesn't mention it). Moreover, I think if the Preview Link feature is broken, Google Chat team may take down the related documents.

Comment: @TonyChou sorry, what I meant verified is registered on your Chat app’s configuration page in Google Cloud console
here the link  https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/preview-links

Comment: Thank you again for replying me. I followed the instructions in the post (as I mentioned earlier) to configure the preview link. If `Preview Link` is currently working, then there must be a setting that I have missed; if it is not working, then it may be a bug in Google Chat(bacause the backend won't receive any message anymore)

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Dyas Yaskur, sorry for wasting your time. I'm sure that Chat Bot in space surely don't receive non-mention messages. But if truely configure `Link previews` which I misconfigured, Google Chat will send request to backend so that we could implement the preview process.