# @mention monitoring in Gchat

Tags: webhooks, mention, google-chat

I would like to monitor @mentions on gchat spaces and call an API for triggering phone call. It shouldn't require any modification on existing spaces like adding a separate user. Can someone share how we could achieve this? Can we create bots or using webhooks or web scrapping?

Comment: The only way I could think of is using a bot, of course you would have to add the bot to the space and would trigger once you mention it.

Comment: But that is not what I want. When there is a mention to a particular member, I would like to have a phone call triggered to that user. So it should be able monitor the whole chat space and trigger when a particular mention happens.

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/350158/manage#basic), explaining the potential usefulness of this functionality.

Comment: related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097228/google-chat-bot-doesnt-receive-non-mention-message-event-in-space/76097688#76097688

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there isn't a specific feature available for that purpose, and it may not be introduced in the future. However, you can utilize the [spaces.messages/list](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/list) endpoint to run a cron job at specified intervals. By checking each message retrieved and identifying if a mention is present, you can then trigger a phone call using Twilio or a similar service.